# Why isn’t this XOR enctryption working? I’m trying to a pass in some values, but it doesn’t work

Tags: javascript

```
function encryptStringWithXORtoHex(input,key) {
    var c = '';
    while (key.length < input.length) {
         key += key;
    }
    for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
        var value1 = input[i].charCodeAt(0);
        var value2 = key[i].charCodeAt(0);

        var xorValue = value1 ^ value2;

        var xorValueAsHexString = xorValue.toString("16");

        if (xorValueAsHexString.length < 2) {
            xorValueAsHexString = "0" + xorValueAsHexString;
        }

        c += xorValueAsHexString;
    }
    return c;
    console.log(c);

}

encryptStringWithXORtoHex(“hello world”, “37526”)
```

So whenever I try to use this code to encrypt “hello world” in xor with the key “37526”, nothing comes up in the console. Anyone know why?

Comment: You're returning the value before logging, so the function ends before it logs.

Comment: You'll want to write `console.log(encryptStringWithXORtoHex("hello world", "37526"))` (notice also the proper non-typographical quotes).